# Count number of pairs of two numbers less than or equal to N such that Sum of the digits of numbers of pair is Prime

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

Given a number N, count all pairs (X,Y) such that sum of to the digits of X and Y is prime. Conditions are as follows.

- 1 <= N <= 10^50
- 0 <= X,Y <= N
- (X,Y) and (Y,X) are same pair.

I could think of brute force approach. In which I need to put two loops ranging from 1 to N and compute sum of digits for each x and y pair and check whether its prime or not. But its not an optimal solution as N has range 10^50.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: problem is independent of Language, although I have added Java as language

Comment: Consider that X and Y have at most 100 digits, each digit being at most 9. Thus the maximum sum of digits is 9000, and minimum is of course 0. Now loop through every prime in [0, 9000] and count how many ways this prime can be partitioned into two (at most) 50 digit numbers.

Comment: could you be more specific about partition or can you provide mathematical formula to compute that(as each partition can be satisfied with different numbers).

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I'm probably being dense but I don't see why the maximum sum of 100 digits is 9000 rather than 900 -- what am I missing?

Comment: @cdlane: oops, haha, no I'm always the dense one. It should be 900.

Answer (score 1):

I've been taking a stab at this -- it took me a couple of tries just to understand the problem.  I want to write up what I learned before I give up and move onto something easier!

First, my rework of @shiva's solution that produces correct output faster:

```
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

def sum_of_digits(number):
    summation = 0

    while number > 0:
        summation += number % 10
        number //= 10

    return summation

@lru_cache()
def is_prime(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    divisor = 3

    while divisor * divisor <= number:
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False
        divisor += 2

    return True

maximum = int(sys.argv[1])

count = 0

for i in range(maximum + 1):
    sum_i = sum_of_digits(i)

    for j in range(i, maximum + 1):
        if is_prime(sum_i + sum_of_digits(j)):
            count += 1

print(count)
```

I use this as a benchmark below for both speed and accuracy.

The number of primes needed is trivial, even for 10^50, and can/should be computed ahead.  The number of digit sums that are generated is also relatively small and can be stored/hashed.  My solution hashes all the possible digit sums from 0 to 10^N, storing the number of times each sum is generated as the value.  It then does a pair of nested loops over the digit sums (keys) and if the sum of those sums is a prime, it adds to the count the product of the number of ways each sum can be computed (i.e. multiplies the values).

```
import sys
from math import ceil
from collections import defaultdict

VERBOSE = False

def sum_of_digits(number):
    summation = 0

    while number:
        summation += number % 10
        number //= 10

    return summation

def sieve_primes(n): 
    sieve = [False, False] + [True] * (n - 1)

    divisor = 2

    while divisor * divisor <= n: 
        if sieve[divisor]: 
            for i in range(divisor * divisor, n + 1, divisor): 
                sieve[i] = False
        divisor += 1

    return [number for number in range(2, n + 1) if sieve[number]]

power = int(sys.argv[1])  # testing up to 10 ** power

maximum_sum_of_digits = 18 * power
primes_subset = sieve_primes(maximum_sum_of_digits)

sums_of_digits = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(10 ** power + 1):
    sums_of_digits[sum_of_digits(i)] += 1

if VERBOSE:
    print('maximum sum of digits:', maximum_sum_of_digits)
    print('maximum prime:', primes_subset[-1])
    print('number of primes:', len(primes_subset))
    print('digit sums cached', len(sums_of_digits))

primes_subset = set(primes_subset)

count = 0

for i in sums_of_digits:
    sum_i = sums_of_digits[i]

    for j in sums_of_digits:
        if i + j in primes_subset:
            count += sum_i * sums_of_digits[j]

print(ceil((count + 2) / 2))  # hack to help adjust between duples and no duples count; sigh
```

(Turn on the `VERBOSE` flag to see more information about the problem.)

Unfortunately, this counts both (X, Y) and (Y, X), contrary to the problem specification, so there's an approximate correction hack at the end of the code to adjust for this.  (Please suggest an exact correction!)  I call my result an approximation but it usually only undercounts by 1 or 2.  Unlike @shiva's code, this one takes a power of 10 as its argument since it's goal is to see how close to 10^50 it can get.

> Would be glad to see a result for N=10^50 (or at least 10^8) – MBo

```
        @Shiva reworked            My Attempt
          exact    secs        approx    secs
10^1         24    0.03            24    0.03
10^2       1544    0.04          1544    0.04
10^3     125030    0.49        125029    0.04
10^4   12396120   51.98      12396119    0.05
10^5 1186605815 6223.28    1186605813    0.14
10^6                     113305753201    1.15
10^7                   11465095351914   12.36
10^8                 1120740901676507  137.37
10^9               105887235290733264 1626.87
```

@shiva's revamped solution is useless above 10^4 and mine bogs down above 10^8.  So getting to 10^50 is going to take a different approach.  I hope some of this code and analysis will help towards that effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this python code and debug:

```py
def sumofdigits(num):
  sum=0
  while num>0:
    sum+=num%10
    num=num//10
  return sum
def isprime(num):
  if num==0:
    return False
  i = 2
  while i<num:
    if num%i==0:
      return False
    i+=1
  return True
number = int(input("Enter number:"))
for i in range(0,number+1):
  for j in range(i,number+1):
    if isprime(sumofdigits(i)+sumofdigits(j)):
      print(i,j);
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Would be glad to see a result for N=10^50 (or at least 10^8)

Comment: You should consider range of X and Y. Its not an optimal solution.

Comment: Not optimised, but X and Y are in range. Can you tell me where X, Y are not in range?

Comment: X can have value from 1 to 10^50. Provided brute force will not help.

Comment: Yes, but I gave input as 10 right? thats why it is taking upto 10 only. It is not optimised solution I agree.

Comment: If I read the output correctly, this solution incorrectly includes 1 in the set of primes?

Comment: @MBo, I've added a solution that both reworks this code for accuracy and performance as well as adds my own solution that reaches for 10^8 (but likely not much further).